# Accessing Data inside hash / array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello I have the following object ( simplified for example sake )

```
object = { note_attributes: [{ name: "Order_Count", value: 2 }] }
```

I am looking to access specifically the `"Order_Count"`. How do I do this in my rails app?

I have tried `note_attributes.name` and `note_attributes[name]` but I have not had any luck.

Comment: That appears to be a key-value pair from a hash, which is not an object (the reason for the downvote, I expect). You need to make it a hash by enclosing it in braces. (If you don't, whether reasonable or not, expect more downvotes). While you're at it I suggest you assign it to a variable (e.g, `h = { note_attributes.. }`) so readers can refer to the variable in answers and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do `note_attributes[0].name` to access it

Answer (score 1):

`object[:note_attributes][0][:name]`

Update because of the comments:

`object.note_attributes[0].name`

Comment: I put the name of your variable as "object", but it should be something else.

Comment: The variable name is not shown in your piece of code.

Comment: yeah i caught that and did replace it as well, but it still didnt work.  It gave me undefined method `[]' for #<ShopifyAPI::Order:0x00000000XXXXXXXX> ( which is my object )

Comment: Can you try `object.note_attributes[0].name`? Also, I suggest you put the class name `ShopifyAPI::Order` in the question. Are you using `shopify_api` gem? If so, add it as a tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array with a single hash inside. So you need to access the first element of the array to get your hash like this: `note_attributes[0]` or `note_attributes.first`.

Then you can access elements inside the hash. In this case, your keys are symbols, which look like this: `:name`.

Ruby hashes used to look like: `{ :name => "Order_Count" }`, but now you can use a colon instead of the arrow. Ruby makes it look especially nice when you use a symbol as a key and lets you do: `{ name: "Order_Count" }` (which is what you have done).

So, to get the attribute with the key `:name` out of the hash in your array you would do this:

```
note_attributes[0][:name]
```

or

```
note_attributes.first[:name]
```